# What happens when I overload an operator as a template?

Tags: c++, templates, operators

I am writing some notes, and just for the sake of compiling, I added an `operator<<` overloaded function for the `ostream` as a `template`. It compiles just fine but, since I overloaded the operator with `class type` inside the `<>` of `template` and passed that type as the second input for the overloaded function, won't it use the new operator for EVERY class that I define from now on? 
Here's my code for reference.
It's purely for note purposes, it has no functionality.

```
template <class type>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& s, type x){
  s << x.getsmth();
  //...
}
```

Comment: *"won't it use the new operator for EVERY class that I define from now on?"* Yes, essentially. Which is why adding such a templated overload would be unwise.

Comment: And of course, the compiler would complain like crazy if it didn't find the methods called in there. That's what I thought.

Comment: Not for EVERY class, only to those that don't have another overloading with a better match (e.g. specific to the class) and are in the same namespace as the template you defined (due to [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) rules).

Answer (score 0):

I'm myself a novice when it comes to SFINAE, but it seems like you are correct, this template will be used for classes which don't offer `getsmth()`, even though the body doesn't compile. You can prevent this from happening with SFINAE though, this seems to work as expected:

```
template <class T, typename = decltype(T().getSomething())>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& s, T& x){
  s << x.getSomething();
  return s;
}
```

Demo: http://cpp.sh/8fyk

Comment: Yeah, you could actually do that, but what's the point? If you just define it inside the class, it'll save you the trouble.
I guess you could do another thing. Define the method outside any class, and then add `friend` followed by the first line of the classes you want. Although that would only work with classes that have child classes.

Comment: This example is working with any classes that has the member function `getSomething` defined in it. It will work with classes that comes from external code and won't tie up your classes in a specific hierarchy. It may come useful too if you want to add a function `print` in any of your class and make this function work.